# Read once stream for multiple consumers

Tags: c#, inputstream

We have a few (big) image files. We wanted to create thumbnails from those files and at the same time record their MD5 sums.

Idealy we wanted the program to read those files only once, and never positions back. However since the data serves for two consumers, although we can create multiple threads we cannot avoid multiple read of the files.

So the requirement is: assuming a read-only, forward only stream, how to use it to feed both a `new Bitmap(stream)` and a call to `md5.ComputeHash(stream)`? (The solution should be extended to other stream consumers)

How can we do this?

Comment: I have [one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/244314/226545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case:

Instead of calling `md5.ComputeHash(stream)`, call `new CryptoStream(stream, md5, CryptoStreamMode.Read)`.
This stream will mirror the original stream, but will also pass it through the MD5 hasher.
Once the stream has been read to the end, the `md5` instance will hold the hash.

Comment: Is the hash accessible through `md5.Hash` property?

Comment: Also your order of parameters is wrong - it is `new CryptoStream(stream, md5, CryptoStreamMode.Read)`.

Comment: This answer isn't extendable, but is good enough for just this case. Marked as correct, but want to see more general answers as well.